# UITextField becomeFirstResponder not working in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, ios6

i have a UITextField that is subview of a UIView that is set as tableHeaderView of a UITableView.
for some reason the textfield does not invoke the keyboard when clicked in iOS6 (in previous OS it works just fine).

the implementation is pretty straight forward..
any ideas what can be the problem?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
_tracksTableView.tableHeaderView = _tableHeaderView;  //this view contains the     _playlistNameTextField

- (IBAction)saveButtonClicked
{
    [self toggleTextField];
}

- (void)toggleTextField
{
   if (_textFieldVisible)
   {

    [_playlistNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [_playlistNameTextField fadeOut:0.2 delegate:self];
    [_saveAsPalylistButton fadeIn:0.2 delegate:self];
            _textFieldVisible = NO;
    }
   else 
   {
            [_playlistNameTextField setText:@""];
            [_saveAsPalylistButton fadeOut:0.2 delegate:self];
            [_playlistNameTextField fadeIn:0.2 delegate:self startSelector:nil      stopSelector:@selector(launchKeyboard)];
            UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [self barButtonItemWithTitle:NLS(@"Cancel") action:@selector(toggleTextField)];
            [barButton.customView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, barButton.customView.frame.size.width, _playerTitleView.frame.size.height)];
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;
           _textFieldVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)launchKeyboard
{
    [_playlistNameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This was solved. the function: - (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder (which was override in the base view controller of my controller) should have returned FALSE.